# Referencing other sheets with dynamically changable sheet names

Tags: string, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets that gathers values from three other sheets that have strict naming rules: the name of these sheets contains the year in a YY format followed by an underscore, followed by the month in a MM format followed by an underscore, and finally one of the three posts.

So it looks like `17_12_TISZT` for the December, 2017 post1 sheet or `18_01_APOLO` for the January, 2018 post2 sheet.

Is it possible to create a string that changes dynamically with the ongoing date (year and month) so I won't have to manually find and replace the references?

I have tried constructing the string needed with the following formula:

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(TODAY();4);2)&"_"&MID(TODAY();6;2)&"_TISZT"
```

this gave me `17_12_TISZT`; exactly the name of one of the three Sheets I need to reference.

My formulas that need to use the reference, however, cannot seem to work this way. Instead of referencing `'17_12_TISZT'!RANGE` I tried:

`'RIGHT(LEFT(TODAY();4);2)&"_"&MID(TODAY();6;2)&"_TISZT'"!`

and some other ways like this, but ran into errors all the time.

What am I doing wrong?
Can this type of cross-referencing be accomplished in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use INDIRECT():

```
=INDIRECT("'" & RIGHT(LEFT(TODAY();4);2)&"_"&MID(TODAY();6;2)&"_TISZT" & "'!A1")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I never used/heard of that formula before, even though I have tried Googling my question :-/